# Check if any WC_Order back-order item(s) exceed(s) current stock

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm building a specific notification for the customer when the order they just placed contains product(s) in backorder, and more specifically when the purchased quantity exceeded the current stock of the product(s).

The notification will be added to the Thank you page using the appropriate hook (`woocommerce_thankyou` - which passes the `$order` object as the only param), and also to the confirmation email sent to the customer (either `WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order` or `WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order`- which also both pass the `$order` object as one of their params).

So everything up to the point where I have an order ID is determined, checked, and working.

What I'm looking for is a robust and bug-free solution that will be given an order ID as the param, and will return a simple true if any of the products of that order is on backorder, and the purchased quantity exceeded the available stock before the purchase (I suppose this can also be calculated by checking if the current quantity is negative?). Of course this solution must work with simple products or variations.

Any help please?